# HTML CSS tips for browser

Tags: html, css

so I am new to html, css and doing a online course. so At the moment building a simple website. So my Website has table of content which is aligned in centred. Now I am working on a 27 inch imac. So the page max width is high. But when I resize the the browser unfortunately my table of content dowsnt stay in middle . Any tips will be great: here is  part of my html and css code :

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  max-width: 2500px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #DBE4DF;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.TableofContents {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 1000px;
}

ol {
  list-style-position: inside;
  counter-reset: item;
  text-align: centre;
}

ol>li {
  counter-increment: item;
}

ol ol>li {
  display: block;
}

ol ol>li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Table of Contents</h1>
<div class="TableofContents">
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#Lecture1">Lecture1: World Wide Web and HTML Basics</a></li>
    <ol>
      <li><a href="#Lecture1.1">Word Wide Web</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Lecture1.2">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Lecture1.3">HTML Tags and Elements</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Lecture1.4">Are Computers Stupid?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Lecture1.5">Block Elements vs Inline Elements</a></li>
    </ol>
  </ol>
  </br>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to work on the margin.  Assuming it is `.TableofContents` that is supposed to be centered, the css would be:

```
.TableofContents {
    margin: 5px auto;
}
```

The auto here being important because it handles the left/right part of the margin.  Here is a link from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp) that should get you started with responsive margins.

Comment: The `ol` is inside `.TableofContents`, unless you want it centered inside of the `TableofContents` container.  If the entire content is what you want to center, then it is `TableofContents`, otherwise, try `ol { margin: 5px auto }`